# How to convert Windows.UI.Core KeyRoutedEventArgs to Windiws.Forms.KeyEventArgs?

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp, .net-core

I need to convert KeyRoutedEventArgs to KeyEventArgs in my UWP app.

I have this :

```
private void Grid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        char? chr = EasyScript.KeyboardEventToChar(e);
        if (chr != null)
        {
            eScript.Parse((char)chr);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleException(ex);
    }
}
```

EasyScript.KeyboardEventToChar accepts only Windows.forms.KeyEventArgs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create it by yourself, converting the [`Key` enum property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.virtualkey) to [`Keys` enum property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx), providing that value to [`KeyEventArgs` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.keyeventargs.aspx):

```
new KeyEventArgs((Keys)(int)e.Key);
```

Or you can use that property by yourself, getting the char from it.

Comment: The problem is i am referencing Windows.Forms in my UWP app. I think this is not supported. getting the error of ResourceSet in CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary.

Comment: You still may do checks for a char by yourself

Comment: What kind of checks?

Comment: Switch over `e.Key`